# Expanding $(a+bX)^c$ when $c \notin \mathbb{N}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve something that looks like this: $$(a+bX)^c,~c \notin \mathbb{N}$$

so that I can solve something that looks like this: $$ X^l=\frac{r}{(a+bX)^c}$$

where {$l,a,b$} are all just arbitrary numbers whereas $c\in(-1,0)$ is not an integer. It seems to be a simple problem and I am overlooking something easy here.

The closest I have gotten so far is:

\begin{align}
  X^l(a+bX)^c &= r \\
  [X^l(a+bX)^c]^{\frac{1}{c}} &= r^{\frac{1}{c}} \\
  X^{\frac{l}{c}}(a+bX) &= r^{\frac{1}{c}}
\end{align}

Comment: Did you try Gamma function?

Comment: I didn't - so just gamma function of both sides and try to isolate X?  -- not sure how this would work here ... my algebra is really not great because I've not had a formal algebra course.

Comment: No. You might get polynomial representation using Gamma function.

Comment: No - I have not tried this. I am not sure I know how to do this. Wouldn't I need to know something about X to do this?

Comment: @123 You could try numerical methods.

Comment: @ALex Francisco -- I need a way to do this relatively simply. Do you have suggestion on how to do this? This is a small piece of solving a much problem.

Comment: @123 Is there any other property of $a,b,c,l,r$ for approximating $x$ such as $l\gg1$ or $\dfrac ab\gg1$?

Comment: @AlexFrancisco -- I know $l \approx -2.5$. We can say $b=1$  and $a$ here can vary but should be, on average, $a \in [3,5]$.

Comment: It is still not quite clear what you want. The function (on the LHS in the last line) is increasing, convex, and smooth, so Newton's method will converge in just a few iterations. The explicit formula for the solution is out of question. So, what are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understood properly your post and the comments you gave, we have
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
   - 1 < c < 0 \hfill \cr 
  l,a,b,r \in R \hfill \cr 
  X^{\,l}  = {r \over {\left( {a + bX} \right)^{\,c} }} \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

Definitely you cannot look for a closed formula: you can go only
numerically, by iterated approximations.

However, you shall better first to clear up the situation about the parameters . In fact
 - since $c$ is not integer, $a+bX$ cannot be negative, otherwise you enter into the complex field;
 - same, if $l$ is not an integer , then $X$ cannot be negative and $r$ as well cannot be negative.

So let us assume
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
   - 1 < c < 0 \hfill \cr 
  0 < d =  - c < 1 \hfill \cr 
  l =  - 2.5 \hfill \cr 
  b = 1 \hfill \cr 
  0 < a,r \in R \hfill \cr 
  0 = r\left( {a + X} \right)^{\,d} X^{\,5/2}  - 1 = f(X) \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

Now much depends on the approximation that you need for the solution.

For instance, rewriting the last in this way
$$
a^{\,d + 5/2} \left( {1 + X/a} \right)^{\,d} \left( {X/a} \right)^{\,5/2}  = 1/r
$$
and assuming $X<<a$, a crude approximation would be to put the binomial at $1$ and get
$$
X = r^{\, - 2/5} a^{\, - 2d/5} 
$$
after which you can use this value to further develop the terms in $X$ around that, 
either as binomial, or taking the logarithm of both sides.

Otherwise, rewriting it as
$$
f(X) = \left( {a + X} \right)^{\,d} X^{\,5/2}  - 1/r = 0
$$
and having
$$
f(0) =  - 1/r\quad f(1) = \left( {a + 1} \right)^{\,d}  - 1/r
$$
suppose $f(1)$ is positive (otherwise you move to $f(2)$ or first $X$ that renders it positive)
and apply the [secant method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method), to get
$$
X_0  = {1 \over {r\left( {a + 1} \right)^{\,d} }}
$$
and reiterate.